# Subdomain not resolving to IP

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, subdomain, a-record

I created a subdomain `http://themes.ibrogram.com` and it doesn't seem to work, however `http://ibrogram.com/themes` does work.

I've had this issue for ages using an A record and can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

```
; Domain: ibrogram.com
; Exported (y-m-d hh:mm:ss): 2011-11-26 10:57:43
;
; This file is intended for use for informational and archival
; purposes ONLY and MUST be edited before use on a production
; DNS server.
;
; In particular, you must update the SOA record with the correct
; authoritative name server and contact e-mail address information,
; and add the correct NS records for the name servers which will
; be authoritative for this domain.
;
; For further information, please consult the BIND documentation
; located on the following website:
;
; http://www.isc.org/
;
; And RFC 1035:
;
; http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt
;
; Please note that we do NOT offer technical support for any use
; of this zone data, the BIND name server, or any other third-
; party DNS software.
;
; Use at your own risk.

; SOA Record
IBROGRAM.COM.   3600    IN  SOA ns49.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net (
                2011112600
                28800
                7200
                604800
                86400
                )

; A Records
@   3600    IN  A   199.38.116.24

; CNAME Records
www 3600    IN  CNAME   @
mobilemail  3600    IN  CNAME   mobilemail-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net
pda 3600    IN  CNAME   mobilemail-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net
email   3600    IN  CNAME   email.secureserver.net
imap    3600    IN  CNAME   imap.secureserver.net
mail    3600    IN  CNAME   pop.secureserver.net
pop 3600    IN  CNAME   pop.secureserver.net
smtp    3600    IN  CNAME   smtp.secureserver.net
ftp 3600    IN  CNAME   @
webmail 3600    IN  CNAME   webmail.secureserver.net
e   3600    IN  CNAME   email.secureserver.net

; MX Records
@   3600    IN  MX  0   smtp.secureserver.net
@   3600    IN  MX  10  mailstore1.secureserver.net

; NS Records
@   3600    IN  NS  ns49.domaincontrol.com
@   3600    IN  NS  ns50.domaincontrol.com
```

Comment: Can we get zone file for ibrogram.com pasted in here?

Comment: @Rilindo Zone file?

Comment: Its a file that contains your domain name as well as subdomains with the corresponding IPs or other domains attached.

Comment: @Rilindo Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add a zone file entry with the following A record:

```
themes    3600    IN  A   199.38.116.24
```

You can verify that it resolves by typing

```
dig themes.ibrogram.com
```

Note that you still need to ensure that your web server is setup for named-based hosting. Assuming that it is Apache, it will be something like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName themes.ibrogram.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/themes
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @user102205 : and **never** name `themes  IN  A` type records subdomains, they are **HOSTS**